# Writing 00 in hex char array

Tags: c++, hex

I have to send commands to some device with the hexadecimal format.

I have succeeded to send hex commands with `"\xAA\xBB\xCC\xDD\xEE"` and `"\xAA\xBB\xCC%c\xEE"` with `%c` containing a certain decimal value.

But I can't send `00` value like `"\xAA\xBB\xCC0x00\xEE"`.

I've seen many topic on this, but no solution fits my need. I tried different things, like:

```c
sprintf(char_array, "\xAA\xBB\xCC%d%d\xEE", 0,0);   
sprintf(char_array, "\xAA\xBB\xCC0x00\xEE");
```

But I can't find the correct solution. If I understand correctly, `00` indicates the end of my char array, and I need to do an escape sequence to insert the hex value into my array.

To sum up : I can send any hex commands except when they contains `00`.

Comment: Why not use `%c` directly? `sprintf(char_array, "\xAA\xBB\xCC%c\xEE", 0);`

Comment: You know you need an escape sequence, then use that. (Also string ends at `'\0'`, so `sprintf()` cannot used for that): `char data[] = "\xAA\xBB\xCC\x00\xEE"; memcpy(char_array, data, sizeof(data));`

Comment: [`sprintf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) return the number of characters formatted, so it will be useful to send the commands.

Comment: Do you want an actual zero there, or digits? If you want digits, `'0'` will not terminate any string and poses no problem. If you want an actual zero, `%c` or `%d` will not help, but `char_array[3] = 0` will.

Comment: @MikeCAT %c with 0 doesn't work.

Comment: @Bazziil [%c with 0 works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ju1wuqX5gWmFL8JC). Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: Well these commands are used to control the zoom of a camera. I can launch a zoom with a certain command then stop/dezoom at anytime with another commands. I'm sending these char array into uart and i got no change (with the 0x00) from the video and i know that these commands works, because i tested them with console command.

Comment: What exactly is the command format? Your successful examples both have one `char` in the place you indicate. If the receiver expects one character and you send several (for instance `"00"` or `"0x00"`) then it is going to be unhappy.

Comment: The command format is : 51 23 21 21 ff. I successfully sent these commands using sprintf("\x51\x23\x21\x21\xff");  With this command "\xAA\xBB\xCC%c\xEE" %c = 48 which is translates by 0x30.

Comment: @Bazziil Decimal 48, hex 0x30, is the ASCII character `'0'`, which would be `"\xAA\xBB\xCC0\xEE"`, aka `sprintf(char_array, "\xAA\xBB\xCC%c\xEE", '0');` in your code examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MikeCAT and @Remy Lebeau said : `sprintf(char_array, "\xAA\xBB\xCC%c\xEE", '0');`
work.
The issue was that later in my code I have a `strlen(char_array)` which returned :

6 for `sprintf(char_array, "\xAA\xBB\xCC\xDD\xEE", 22);` and

4 for `sprintf(char_array, "\xAA\xBB\xCC%c\xEE", 0);`

So for now i will fix the size at 6.
Thanks for your help.